# Calculate sum from data that is formatted in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

```
$query_stoday = "SELECT sum(amount), sum(amtnaira) 
                 FROM transactions
                 WHERE transtype = 'buy' 
                       AND batch !='' 
                       AND date2 ='$date2'";
```

I use the above code to calculate total amount for the day but i notice it only calculates the numbers before the **comma**. Example, in **2,780.00**, it adds only **2 and ignores the numbers after the comma**. Please how do i make the query to calculate everything?

Comment: You may be suffering from [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135887): You should be fixing how those numbers are stored instead of worrying about cleaning them later.

Comment: Are you storing those numbers as numbers or in a text field?

Answer (score 2):

use this query

```
SELECT sum(REPLACE((amount), ',', '')), 
sum(REPLACE((amtnaira), ',', '')) 
FROM transactions WHERE transtype = 'buy' AND batch !='' AND date2 ='$date2'
```

this is what you needed.

Comment: I got "Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FORMAT'" when i ran the query

Comment: @SunejGlobal i have edited my answer. Try it. now it will work.

Comment: I just tried it and the results are 0.00 which is not correct. //To get amount sold today

$query_stoday = "SELECT sum(REPLACE((amount), ',', '')), sum(REPLACE((amtnaira), ',', '')) FROM transactions WHERE transtype = 'buy' AND batch !='' AND date2 ='$date2'";
$stoday = mysql_query($query_stoday, $egold1) or die(mysql_error());
$row_stoday = mysql_fetch_assoc($stoday);
$totalRows_stoday = mysql_num_rows($stoday);

Answer (score 0):

you should use ***PHP*** [number_format](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.number-format.php) function

Answer (score 0):

You can frame the query by this way

```
    SELECT REPLACE((amount), ',', '') as amount, 
    REPLACE((amtnaira), ',', '') as amtnaira 
    FROM transactions WHERE transtype = 'buy' AND batch !='' AND date2 ='$date2'

    //Then format the 'amount' and 'amtnaira' values like this

    $sum_amount += number_format($row['amount'],2);
    $sum_amtnaira += number_format($row['amtnaira'],2);
```

This should work.